# running an existing Wordpress site from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

Perhaps I am being a bit thick on my research and haven't nailed what I have to do in order to achieve what I want to achieve so here's my question:
I have an existing Wordpress site that has been handed over to me. How can I grab all those files, open them from my VS Code and run the project locally? Do I need to install WP on my machine prior doing that? Do I need any VS Code extensions - as in PHP, MySQL - to be able to run the project? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try [Local](https://localwp.com).

Comment: thank you, tried local but I keep having issues when I try to import the existing site via uploading a zip folder. I have read it is because of the wrong files being uploaded...I have compressed wpcontent (as recommended) and uploaded it...still no luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've been handrolling, but XAMPP is pretty common. And yes, if you're going to edit the site, you'll want the vs code php extension. The wordpress install should probably come in with the site, but if not, it's very simple. I'm assuming you have the database, because if you don't, you don't really have the site at all. This is where you start:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/setting-up-a-development-environment/

Comment: yep, installed XAMPP and am now working on my local machine, ta very much !